# Forgot Username Issue in Joomla

Tags: joomla

i forgot my username & password but when i was trying to reset my password or username following message was display: Notice
Reset password failed: Invalid email address

Comment: Are you the SuperAdmin/Owner of the site or a standard user on somebody elses site?

Comment: do you have access to the db ?

Answer (score 0):

Log into your database via phpMyAdmin

enter the users table in the left menu.

Find the user you want to reset the password for and click the edit icon next to them.

Next to "password", choose MD5 in the drop down, type in a new password, and then click Go.